# Mongodb: $group after $lookup yield timeout error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

To simplify the question. Basically I have two tables. One is revision and another one is bot.
The revision collection's main structure is :

```
user: <username>
timestamp: <ISODate>
```

The bot collection contains a list of bot name:

```
name: <botname>
```

If one revision's user is in the bot collection, then it is a bot revision.

What I am trying to do is to get the distribution of revisions based on year, and in each year, get the distribution of regular users and bot users.

**Issue :**

What I have attempted is firstly use `'$lookup'` to find all of the bot user, then `'$group'`.

However, these two pipelines can work separately but not work together.

Here is when they execute together, a timeout error occurs.
[image: Two pipelines execute together]
When they run separately, it works fine.
[image]

I cannot figure out what happens. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use [robo3T](https://robomongo.org) to access MongoDB which is more convinient sometimes as where you can execute queries like below just as the way you do in mongo shell. Not sure why you're doing `_id : '$year'` but it has to be `_id: { $year: "$timestamp" }`. Try below aggregation query :

```
db.revisions.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "bots",
        localField: "user",
        foreignField: "name",
        as: "bot"
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { $year: "$timestamp" }, // get year from `timestamp` field
        regularUser: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $size: "$bot" }, 0, 1 ] } },
        botUser: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $size: "$bot" }, 1, 0 ] } }
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S3tLisz8fUZ)

**Note :** Do not forget to maintain indexes on both collections, At least on `user` & `name` fields.